# python turtle goto is not working

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have written a turtle programma that uses data to make a line on a graph chart. Everything works fine except i call the make_line() in the chartlines. The goto is excecuted but doesn't draw a line. Even if i put a turtle.down() before i go in to the While loop it doesn't draw a line.

```
import turtle


def Change_tekenpunt(x,y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.down()


def xAxisTurtle(days):

    xAxis = turtle
    xAxis.ht()
    Change_tekenpunt(-300, -220)
    x = -275
    for i in range(0,days+1):
        xAxis.write(i)
        Change_tekenpunt(x, -220)
        x+=25

def yAxisTurtle():
    yAxis = turtle
    yAxis.ht()
    Change_tekenpunt(-310, -200)
    y = -160
    for i in range(0, 1601, 200):
        yAxis.write(i)
        Change_tekenpunt(-330, y)
        y+=50

def point():
    turtle.begin_fill() # Begin to fill color in a shape
    turtle.color("black")
    turtle.circle(3) # Draw a circle
    turtle.end_fill() # Fill the shape

def make_line(x, y,gegevens):
    Change_tekenpunt(x,y)
    i = 0 
    while i < len(gegevens):
        y = gegevens[i][0]
        y //= 4
        Change_tekenpunt(x,y)
        x+=25
        i+=1


def chartlines(x,y,days, gegevens):

      char = turtle
      Change_tekenpunt(x,y) 
      char.tracer(0,0)
      char.speed(0)
      char.ht()
      point()
      for i in range(days):      
          char.forward(25)
          char.left(270)
          point()
          char.left(90)

      char.left(180)
      char.forward(25*days)
      char.left(270)

      for i in range(8):
          char.forward(50)
          char.left(90)
          point()
          char.left(270)

      char.left(180)
      char.forward(400)

      xAxisTurtle(days)
      yAxisTurtle()
      make_line(x, y,gegevens)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Ok, `make_line()` takes 3 arguments but you're giving 4 in the `chartlines` function.

Comment: i did with spaces, cause i press tab i goes to the send button in the website. Sorry for that, i took that out on my project already only forgot to add it here

Comment: How do you call the `chartlines` function? what arguments does it take? can you give an example?

Comment: turtlefunctions.chartlines(-300,-200, 30, gegevens) and gegevens is [(200,),(300,),(400)] its data for a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Change_tekenpunt` function. You need to keep the `turtle.down()` while drawing the graph. So, you'll need to make some changes to the `Change_tekenpunt` function as follows:

```
def Change_tekenpunt(x,y,up=True):
    if up:
        turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.down()
```

You use this function to draw the chart lines and also the graph. I've added an extra `up` argument (which defaults to `True`) because you need to set this to `False` whenever you're drawing a graph. It has to be down while it's moving. Therefore, in the `make_line` function, in the while-loop, add the `False` argument to the `Change_tekenpunt` function call.

```
def make_line(x, y,gegevens):
    Change_tekenpunt(x,y)
    i = 0 
    while i < len(gegevens):
        y = gegevens[i][0]
        y //= 4
        Change_tekenpunt(x, y, False) #add  the False argument here
        x+=25
        i+=1
```

Finally, in the `chartlines` function, set the `.tracer` to `(1, 0)`.

<strike>`char.tracer(0,0)`</strike>

```
char.tracer(1,0)
```

Or you can *instead* add `turtle.update()` at the end of the `Change_tekenpunt` function.
Hope this helps.